# what the different between lists and sets in dart ? . the question asked before but about java

Tags: dart

I know some differences like
list = [] ;
set = {}

set have different method like intersection() and others I forget them
but what's the main different between them ?

Comment: [Core difference](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/Set-class.html): "Set class : A collection of objects in which each object can occur only once."

Comment: that's a good point

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [List](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/List-class.html) is an ordered collection of elements where the same element may occure several times at different positions.

A [Set](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/Set-class.html) is (usually) an unordered collection of unique elements. The uniqueness is evaluated by using [`==`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) and [`hashCode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html).

```
main() {
  var x = 1;
  var y = 1;
  var z = 2;
  
  var list = <int>[];
  list.add(x);
  list.add(y);
  list.add(z);
  list.add(x);
  print(list); // 4 elements [1, 1, 2, 1]
  
  var set = <int>{};
  set.add(x);
  set.add(y);
  set.add(z);
  set.add(x);
  print(set); // only 2 elements {1, 2}
}
```