# List of random numbers without repetition

Tags: dart, random

Why does the first code generate a list of random numbers with repetition and the second code a list of numbers without repetition? The difference is only a list declared with `int[]` in (1) and `int{}` in(2).

1.)

```
final generatedRandoms = <int>[];

final rng = Random();
while (generatedRandoms.length < 100) {
  final gr = rng.nextInt(100) + 1;
  generatedRandoms.add(gr);
}
```

2.)

```
final generatedRandoms = <int>{};

final rng = Random();
while (generatedRandoms.length < 100) {
  final gr = rng.nextInt(100) + 1;
  generatedRandoms.add(gr);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what the different between lists and sets in dart ? . the question asked before but about java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66551586/what-the-different-between-lists-and-sets-in-dart-the-question-asked-before)

Comment: The second code is very inefficient. It keeps picking random numbers in the range 1..100 until it has picked all of the numbers. The last number takes *on average* 100 tries to find after finding the next-to-last. Doing `[for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) i]..shuffle()` is much more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this declaration:

```
final generatedRandoms = <int>[];
```

versus

```
final generatedRandoms = <int>{};
```

The first declares a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)), the second declares a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)).

Lists can hold multiple values, even duplicates, while sets cannot have duplicates. Since both loops run until there are 100 items in the container, you *might* get duplicates in the first example and you will not have duplicates in the second.

If you time them, you will notice the second one takes longer on average, because it will geenerate a lot more than 100 random numbers to get to 100 unique numbers.